# Is there any documentation for the python module vim--for vim plugin development?

Tags: python, vim

I have went through a couple blog posts on how to make vim plugins using Python, specifically from `import vim`. I am familiar with simple things such as `vim.current.buffer`, and others. However, I cannot find documentation on this module. Suggestions?

Comment: Latest documentation: http://vimhelp.appspot.com/if_pyth.txt.html Other libraries that extend the default Python library for VIM: 1. https://github.com/amoffat/snake
2. https://github.com/neovim/python-client

Answer (score 4, accepted):

from this presentation "[Vim and Python: Two Great Tastes that Taste Great Together](http://www.tummy.com/presentations/vimpython-20070225/)",

> HOWTO Get Started
>
> ```
> Not very well documented outside of vim.
> In vim: help python
> Look at other python scripts at vim.org
> ```

Comment: This is a [wayback machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20210621190527/https://www.tummy.com/presentations/vimpython-20070225/) link.